# One menu for some pages with links from mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I need to make one menu for some pages, where links will be taken from mongodb. How can I do it in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very experienced with MongoDB.

But you can just put links in the database and retrieve them from the database.

Link te explanetion:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/?

Hope this will help you.